# Micro SD card read only by SD Adapter

Tags: sd-card

I have next problem:

I used to write files on my `MicroSD` card through `USB card reader` . And now my devices (Phone etc) don't see it.

But SD adapter inserted in USB card reader see it perfectly.

Please help. Why it happen?

Comment: Tried http://www.recovery-android.com/android-detect-sd-card.html

Answer (score 0):

Find ".android secure" file under SD Card catalogue or connect your phone to the computer. You will find a file named "smdl2tmp1.asec" or something else. In short, delete the files that have different format with the normal application one. Then, install it again. Or, you can also delete "/mnt/secure/asec/smdl2tmp1.asec" with the terminal virtual machine and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by formatting microSD to exFAT file system. Phone at last recognize it and propose format it. After formatting it became work!